# Joining multiple tables on multiples columns in EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have problem when trying to join multiple tables on multiples columns on EF.

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
    Address,
    AddressName,
    COUNT(AddressCode) AS NumberOfAddress
FROM
    Tbl1
    INNER JOIN Tbl2
    ON Tbl1.AddressID = Tbl2.AddressID2
    INNER JOIN Tbl3 
    ON      (Tbl1.AddressID = Tbl3.AddressID
        AND Tbl2.NewId = Tbl3.NewId)
WHERE
    Tbl2.StartDate >= '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY
    Tbl2.AddressID2,
    Tbl3.AddressID
```

This is my query (just for the joining part) in EF:

```
var query = from Tbl1 DbContext.Tbl1
            join Tbl2 in DbContext.Tbl2
            on Tbl1.AddressID equals Tbl2.AddressID2 
            join Tbl3 in DbContext.Tbl3 
            on new {Tbl1.AddressID, Tbl2.NewId} equals new {Tbl3.AddressID,Tbl3.NewId}
```

But it just doesn't work, neither nor some of its variants I have found on StackOverflow.

How can I make it work?

Comment: what do you want as a result and what is the current error or result?

Comment: *it just doesn't work* Please explain *how* it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

At the first line of your code `in` keyword missing. I fixed it and added `where` and `group by` parts.

```
var query = from Tbl1 in Tbl1s
            join Tbl2 in Tbl2s
                on Tbl1.AddressID equals Tbl2.AddressID2 
            join Tbl3 in Tbl3s
                on new {Tbl1.AddressID, Tbl2.NewId} equals new {Tbl3.AddressID,Tbl3.NewId}
            where Tbl2.StartDate >= new DateTime(2001,1,1)
            group new {Tbl1, Tbl2} by new {Tbl2.AddressID2, Tbl3.AddressID} into g
            select new { 
                g.Key.AddressID2, 
                g.Key.AddressID, 
                NumberOfAddress = g.Count() }
```

Comment: What's the difference?